# Simple modules corresponding to vertices of a quiver with potential.

Tags: algebraic-topology, algebras, graded-modules, quiver, representation-of-algebras

Given a quiver with reduced potential $(Q,W)$. The simple dg module over the complete Jacobian algebra $J(Q,W)$ are in bijection to the set of vertices of Q ? How do the simple modules look like ?

And the modules over the complete path algebra of Q corresponding to a vertex of Q?
How do they look like ?

Comment: Is it possible that the corresponding simple module is just the direct summand of the path algebra corresponding to the lazy path on a vertex i to itself ? But what would right multiplying the scalar (path) j -> i do? In the path-algebra we would get the path j-> i which doesnt exists in the summand of the lazy path. So would the scalar multiplication just be the zero map ?

Comment: I think that's right. (I am more used to the simpler non-dg setup, where that is definitely right.)